# Inter processor interrupts on a particular core

Tags: networking, interrupts

Currently I am looking into a performance issue over NXP platform for DPDK forwarding application. 
following is the setup information:

1. Application running on core 7 and it runs in a tight loop for
   packet I/O processing.
2. 4*10G Network interfaces are connected with
   traffic generator for traffic input.

In running traffic, I observe that core 7 has some task to do in context to IPI handling so that 100% CPU bandwidth is not being utilized by DPDK application.
Below is the snapshot of tail /proc/interrupts.

root@localhost:/usr/local/dpdk/dpaa2# tail /proc/interrupts

```
           CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3       CPU4       CPU5       CPU6       CPU7
394:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0     ITS-fMSI 240024 Edge      vfio-irq[394](dpio.8)
395:          0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0     ITS-fMSI 240025 Edge      vfio-irq[395](dpio.9)
IPI0:      5912         88         90         88         87         86         88        202       Rescheduling interrupts
IPI1:        64       3203       3203       3203       3203       3203       3203       3139       Function call interrupts
IPI2:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0       CPU stop interrupts
IPI3:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0       CPU stop (for crash dump) interrupts
IPI4:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0       Timer broadcast interrupts
IPI5:  48795343         91     146481     146479     146481     146479         32   48816043       IRQ work interrupts
IPI6:         0          0          0          0          0          0          0          0       CPU wake-up interrupts
```

Now I am investigating that which service is responsible to generate these IPI interrupts. In my case IPI5 are being increased continuously.
Can someone help me out to find out the solution. Is there any Linux utility to analyze/back-trace these interrupts ?

Thanks in advance.

Sunil Kumar

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to track most remote wakeup reasons via `perf sched`.
See:

- [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/353295/) for some basics
- [Kernel Wiki](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial) for Documentation
- More examples [Brendon Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/perf.html)

Once you found via the first what you think triggers the IPIs you can use the more detailed examples to track down what exactly happens.

If none of the generic things (more easy to use) things work, try to trace

- [IPI Tracepoints](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.15/source/include/trace/events/ipi.h)

Answer (score 0):

IPI - Inter Processor Interrupt, is generated by one processor to send a task to another processor.

In your case it seems CPU-7 is getting too many IP due to network traffic. Usually network interrupts are sent to CPU-0. As the application that processes packets is running on CPU-7, CPU-0 will handover the packet over IPI.

You may avoid it either by running your application on CPU-0 or pinning the network interrupts to CPU-7.